# Word for parent of a single child?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

Is there a word that means “a parent who has exactly one child”?

**EDIT**: I am asking for purposes of creating a computing construct.  But if there were an answer that is clearly correct for another domain, I’d be delighted to use it.

Comment: Don't think so.

Comment: a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%28mathematics%29)?

Comment: *monogenerative*?

Comment: Some clarification of intended use might be due here, since this answer may be domain dependent; if such a word exists for mammalian or human parentage, it may not be an appropriate term in the domain on generic graph/tree theory. For Example, "Single-Mom" is a useful term in describing human parentage, but it is of little utility in describing mathematical tree structures.

Comment: In the context of computing, *unary node* perhaps?

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps the closest is [*uniparous*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uniparous):

> 1. (of certain animals) producing a single offspring at each birth
> 2. **(of a woman) having borne only one child**
> 3. botany (of a cyme) giving rise to only one branch from each flowering stem

From [Parity (biology)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28biology%29) also [*primipara*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/primipara):

> a woman who has borne but one child or who is parturient for the first time.

Comment: Those only apply specifically to the mother.

Comment: @Mark that is correct; I cannot think of anything better, hence "perhaps."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, also, it's not a very commonly used word. (never heard it myself!), but +1, it's very good.

Answer (score 2):

I offer *one-time*:

> He’s a one-time father.

The verbs “to be a mother” and “to be a father” mean to deliver a child as a parent. Even if a person is already a parent, they can still “be a parent” again:

> I’m going to be a father for the second time.

Oddly, some people seem to use this to refer to labour, not count of children:

> She’s a one-time mother of beautiful twin girls.

It also generalises well (and is way more commonly heard) with higher numbers:

> Mary was a three-time mother, one-time grandmother, and all-around excellent woman.

Comment: The only problem I have with this construction is that it is often used to mean something that was in the past, but is no longer. A "one-time" mother could be a mother who has lost her child, or who for some reason no longer acts as a mother or is estranged.

Comment: Use of "one-time" in this way is also a rather American idiom, which may or may not matter.

Comment: @ghoppe: Yeah, it’s problematic, but it’s the only “native” English thing I could think of.

Comment: News media (at least in the UK) often say, e.g.  "father-of-one".